# Why can we use "inadequate" but not "inspecific"?

Tags: grammar, etymology, adjectives, morphology, negative-prefixes

I find the use of the word "inspecific" very natural. It makes sense and flows easily in sentences I speak and write (to myself at least). However, upon inspection, [it is apparently not a valid English word](http://www.tfd.com/inspecific), instead being [nonspecific](http://www.tfd.com/nonspecific) (A.H.D. 5), [unspecific](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unspecific) (O.D.O.) or something of that sort.

We use the *in-* prefix to negate the primary meanings of words very often, for instance in the words "inadequate" and "invariable". I feel like ignoring all of the signs telling me to use "non-specific" instead of "inspecific" and go with what I find right. What about you? Do you find the word "inspecific" **right** or **wrong**? Why can't we negate it, like we negate many other words, simply through prefixing an *in-*?

Also, as a rule of thumb, [Latin words usually seem to take the in- prefix when negated, whereas Germanic words seem to take the un- suffix](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm). [Variable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=variable&allowed_in_frame=0), [adequate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=adequate&allowed_in_frame=0) and [specific](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=specific&allowed_in_frame=0) have Latin origins according to The Online Etymology Dictionary. Why does specific, a Latin derived word, seem to be an exception?

Comment: do you mean unspecific?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking about. Why unspecific and not inspecific?

Comment: -1 You can use it & people will understand it, but it's not considered a word. Were you to use it in an article for publication in most journals, it would most likely be changed to by the editors or peer reviewers to _nonspecific_ or _unspecific_. This attitude "I feel like ignoring all of the signs telling me to use 'non-specific' instead of 'inspecific' and go with what I find right" is absurd & arrogant. "Why unspecific and not inspecific?" Because that's the way it is in English: _nonspecific_ and _unspecific_ are what we use. They're idiomatic & accepted. Your rant is risible.

Comment: Haha somehow I saw this coming, I guess I really am too stupid for this. I just found it an inconsistency that the language doesn't consider it a word and was wondering if there was an actual reason for why that was the case, other than the designers of the language just choosing not to include it.
PS: I'll stick to programming :P

Comment: @BillFranke I upvoted your comment because the journal publication example was great, you just encouraged me not to use my own "absurd and arrogant" means of expression in related applications

Comment: It's not clear that everything in English is explainable. Nevertheless, you can't ignore the fact that language has a purpose: communication. Shared vocabulary is fundamental to that. You can't just say what you feel like if it isn't part of the language. I could say "bleem" instead of "sugar," but if I did that, I would have a lot trouble getting anyone to pass me the sugar.

Comment: There are no "designers of the language". English isn't Perl or Java or C++. It's the language that we Anglophones use to communicate with each other. Like all natural languages, it defines us in one way as members of a tribe. If you want to be a member in good standing of that tribe, you use the language the way everyone you know uses it. For programming language, you do it because the compiler doesn't understand improper terms or syntax. For natural languages, native speakers don't like to hear **their** language "abused" by other native speakers. Emotions about language run high.

Comment: @John: Please don't bleem-coat your answer. Language is rule based, but we learn the rules from trying to follow others.

Comment: Wouldn't that place the tribe of Anglophones as the effective aggregate designers of the language? By establishing their natural way of using "nonspecific" and "unspecific" as opposed to "inspecific", the expectations of use and what I call the "design" of the language (in the scope of that single word) was hence defined. Inspecific is considered false because the tribe as a hole simply decided to use something else instead?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, I agree, nor did I say otherwise. I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg: I was trying to be funny. It didn't work out too well.

Comment: @Mitch In my defense, I wasn't being 100 percent dense, only 50 percent. I detected the humor in part one, and enjoyed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Wiktionary definition of [*nonspecific*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonspecific), it notes:

> #### Synonyms
>
> [unspecific](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unspecific) (less common), [inspecific](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inspecific) (much less common)

The entry for *inspecific* does include quotations.

Google n-grams shows for [*nonspecific,unspecific,inspecific*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonspecific%2Cunspecific%2Cinspecific&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnonspecific%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunspecific%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinspecific%3B%2Cc0) that the ratios between them is approximately 1000:100:1 respectively, i.e. for every 1000 uses of the word *nonspecific*, there is only 1 use of *inspecific*. This makes it almost unheard of by most people.

As an example, my browser's spellchecker says *inspecific* is misspelt. So you can use *inspecific*, but you need to expect that you will be continuously challenged about it. You can avoid being challenged every time by using *nonspecific* instead, as it is the most common of the three words.

Answer (score -6):

*Inspecific* is not standard English, meaning English speakers will experience confusion when they encounter it. If confusion is your goal, by all means use it. If your goal is to communicate without causing confusion, use a word which is in wide circulation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "why" part of the question.

Comment: @sumelic the reason, the answer to 'why', is implicit and the same for all questions asked in this manner: because people just don't use it and they use commonly other versions. If the description of the history of the word was requested, that might be what _should_ have been asked.