# Why do we say INcomplete but UNcompleted?

Tags: adjectives, morphology, negative-prefixes

I'm a native speaker and it's just occurred to me that this is a strange irregularity:

> "The work is *in*complete." < Fine
>
> "The work is *un*completed." < Less common but still sounds "correct" to my ear
>
> "The work is *incompleted* or *uncomplete*  < Both of these sound wrong.

Are there rules (presumably based on the etymological root of the word) governing when we use *"un"* vs *"in"*, and how does it apply to "complete" here? Why don't we say "incompleted" or "uncomplete"?

Or is it just one of those arbitrary things that isn't supposed to make sense? If there's a difference in meaning between "incomplete" and "uncompleted" I can't think what it might be...

Comment: *un-* versus verbs and *in-* versus nouns?

Comment: Related: *[Why “unequal” but “inequality”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15723)* and *[Are there any patterns to observe in choosing the correct negation prefix to use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2532)* among others.

Comment: Because we're speaking English.  The irregularities of English are actually pretty regular.

Comment: What's that army movie where the Sergeant says, "Most of the missiles are inert - however, some of them are ert."?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know about regular, they are very frequent though.

Comment: @BoldBen - Yeah, but you wouldn't call them "irfrequencies".

Comment: @HotLicks Apologies, I should've included a smiley at the end of my comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The etymological origin of the *root* of the word isn't actually as relevant as whether the *ending* of the adjective is from Latin or from English.

The negative prefix *in-* is not very productive in English<sup>1</sup>: that is, it's rare for a speaker to take an English adjective and attach *in-* to it to create a *new* negative adjective. Rather, *in-* (or *im-, ir-,* or *il-*) mainly shows up on words that already existed with this prefix in Latin or French before they were adapted for use in English. For example, before the word *instability* was used in English, *instabilité* was used in French.

As John Lawler says in his answer, *uncompleted* is derived from the past-participle form of the English verb *complete,* as indicated the by the presence fo the suffix *-ed.* It was not taken directly from a Latin adjective.

In contrast, *complete* is the anglicized form of a Latin adjective *completus* which corresponded to a negative adjective *[incompletus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=incompletus)* (listed in Lewis and Short's Latin Dictionary, although as a "late Lat." word).

The reality is a bit more complicated than the preceding paragraphs suggest. For one thing, *in-* does seem to have had some productivity in English in contexts where it creates a word that *looks like* it could have come from Latin or French, even if there wasn't actually a preexisting Latin or French word of this form. The word *invariant* may be an example of this type: the Oxford English Dictionary's earliest citation for the use of the word "invariant" in English is from 1851, which is earlier than the date of 1877 in the *[Trésor de la langue française informatisé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/invariant)*'s entry for *invariant* as a French word.

The OED entry for the negative prefix *in-* suggests that its usage has changed some over the centuries, and mentions the substantial overlap with the usage of *un-* which has resulted in some amount of variation for a number of words:

> In English *in-* (*il-, im-, ir-*) is a living negative suffix for words of Latin or Romanic origin, freely used, even when no corresponding formation appears in Latin; in this use it interchanges to some extent with the Old English negative *un-,* which is used in native or thoroughly naturalized words, e.g. *incautious, uncautious, in-, un-ceremonious, in-, un-certain, in-, un-communicative, in-, un-devout, in-, un-distinguishable.* In such cases the practice in the 16th and 17th c. was to prefer the form with in-, e.g. *inaidable, inarguable, inavailable,* but the modern tendency is to restrict *in-* to words obviously answering to Latin types, and to prefer un- in other cases, as in *unavailing, uncertain, undevout.*

Keep in mind that this entry "has not yet been fully updated (first published 1899)" and it may have some inaccuracies. I think the author may have been overstating things a bit with the wording "**freely** used": Dixon, who I cited above and link to below, says *in-* is "seldom used to derive new [words]" (p.73) and categorizes it as "scarcely productive" (p. 73-74).

An important category of exceptions to the rule that I suggested in this section is adjectives that have Latin-derived endings but that nonetheless are negated with *un-.* Some even have corresponding *-ity* nouns starting with *in-,* such as *unstable, unable, unequal* vs. *instability, inability, inequality*. Other examples of adjectives with Latin-derived endings but the English negative prefix *un-* are *unusual, unreal, unconscious, unscrupulous, ungenerous, ungracious, unattractive, unexpressive, unresponsive.* I don't have stats on the relative frequencies of adjectives like this vs. adjectives like *impossible, inaccurate, insensitive, intolerant* that have the latinate negative prefix to go with their latinate endings. In general, *un-* is more common than *in-* (similar to how *-able* is more common than *-ible*), so the ending-based "rule" I suggest might be thought of as a rule for when a word *might* start with *in-* rather than a rule for when a word *is likely* to start with *in-.* A related question: [Why can we use "inadequate" but not "inspecific"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113776/why-can-we-use-inadequate-but-not-inspecific)

### Words ending in *-ed* very rarely can be negated by prefixing *in-/im-/ir-/il-*

According to João Bittencourt de Oliveira, "Past participles ending in
*-ed*
take
*un-* [...] *Inexperienced* is the only past participle with the prefix
*in-*"<sup>2</sup>. I suspect that the existence of the related noun *inexperience* is relevant, although I'm not sure exactly how. I think that *experienced* may not be a past participle, strictly speaking: although there is a verb *experience,* the suffix *-(e)d* in English is not only used to form participles or adjectives from verbs, but also to form adjectives from nouns (e.g. "winged" or "armed"), and the meaning of *experienced* seems more in line with this other usage of *-ed.* But whatever the internal structure of *experienced,* the word *inexperienced* still seems to me to have the structure *in-* + *experienced* rather than *inexperience* + *-ed,* which is why I'm uncertain about whether the noun *inexperience* has made any contribution to the use of *in-* in the adjective *inexperienced.*

I was able to find one more possible counterexample to the rule that Oliveira mentions: *indisposed.* The OED also has entries for some other obsolete variant words that are constructed this way, such as *indispersed, inaffected, inabstracted.* (Of course, a participle derived from a verb starting with *in-* will also start with *in-,* e.g. *invalidated,* but in this case the prefixation occurred before the suffixation.)

So we could say that the use of *un-* to negate adjectives ending in the suffix *-ed* is just a tendency rather than an absolute law, but it still seems to be a very strong tendency.

#### Citation footnotes & links

1. *[Making New Words: Morphological Derivation in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=MmTRCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73),*
   by R. M. W Dixon (2014), p. 73-74.
2. "[Negative Prefixes in Technical and Scientific English](http://www.academia.edu/5477081/NEGATIVE_PREFIXES_IN_TECHNICAL_AND_SCIENTIFIC_ENGLISH)", p. 14.

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed it was this deep. Thanks for the detailed response!

Answer (score 41):

The root doesn't matter if it's been reified, contracted, or inflected.
That makes it a different word, with different affordances.

- The opposite of *incomplete* is ***complete***; i.e, all parts are present.
  *Incomplete* means (and meant) that **not** all parts are present.
  [*Complete* comes from Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=complete); it's the past participle of a verb meaning 'fill up, fulfil'.
  The Latin negative *in-* prefix was already attached, **before** the word was borrowed.
- The opposite of *uncompleted* is ***completed***; i.e, *finished, done* (of activities).
  *Completed* is the past participle of the **English** verb *complete*, not a Latin verb.
  Since it's an English verb, it uses the English negative prefix *un-*, not the Latin *in-*.

Comment: Another interesting example along the similar lines is "inevitable" vs. "unavoidable". In one case, the derived term comes straight from Latin. In the other, the verb comes from Latin via French, and then the derivation is done in English.

Comment: So were Jefferson and his committee right when they wrote of man's "unalienable rights" (Declaration of Independence). Or should they have spoken of "inalienable rights"?

Comment: Poetry is not subject to the same morphological restrictions as normal prose. "Right" and "wrong" are not linguistic terms.

Answer (score 5):

> If there's a difference in meaning between "incomplete" and
>   "uncompleted" I can't think what it might be...

For me, something that is *incomplete* is lacking. Something that is *uncompleted* has yet to be done.  The former implies a value judgment, the latter is neutral.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with TIM. incomplete means something which has been started and not finished so its incomplete. Uncompleted means the project/work is yet to be started

Comment: Welcome to ELU, user115525. It would be good to use reference material to inform your answers.