# Why is it some adjectives don't seem to accept negative prefixes and only are used with the negative adverb "not"?

Tags: word-choice, morphology, negative-prefixes

I am specifically thinking of the word *angry*. If *un-* is generally used as a negative prefix applied to words of Germanic origin, why not *angry*, since I believe it comes from Old Norse? Is there a rule that states which adjectives can and cannot accept negative prefixes and must rely upon negative adverbs such as *not*?

Comment: But _un-_ is not generally used as a negative prefix applied to Germanic words. It's true that when _un-_ appears, it's on Germanic words; but this is derivational morphology in English, and thus which Germanic words it appears on is arbitrary, and  _angry_ is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So there is no linguistic reason and it is just based on common usage? I suspected this but wanted confirmation. A student asked me why we say 'unhappy' but not 'unangry' and I was stumped.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's not very accurate to say that *un-* is applied to words of Germanic origin. Many adjectives built on Latin or French bases can be prefixed with *un-,* such as *unpleasant, unrealistic, unlimited, unconditional, uncomfortable,* and hundreds more. I wrote an answer with some other examples [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/466615/77227). It's more accurate to say that the negative prefix *in-/im-/ir-/il-/ig-* occurs exclusively with words of Latinate origin, whereas *un-* is possible with adjectives of any etymological origin, but especially productive with adjectives with certain endings (such as *-ed* or *-ing*).

As you've observed, *un-* cannot be added to all adjectives. There's no simple explanation for it that I know of, so it's just something that I would say needs to be memorized. Googling the topic led me to a 213 page disseration on the topic, "Creative prefixations and the prefix un-: A cognitive linguistic analysis", by Balázs Bernadette (2016)–I only skimmed it, but the length and the parts that I did read are consistent with my guess that there is no simple answer to why *unangry* isn't typically used.